# Wordpress: using $wpdb->get_results instead of mysqli_query causes empty var

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

I'm trying to translate a query built with `mysqli_query` in a wordpress query.
The problem is that using `$wpdb->get_results` I'm getting no results at all. I've even tried with `$wpdb->query` and `$wpdb->get_var` with any results too.

> $MYSQLi contains the database informations as you can imagine
>   Of course all the variables are fine! They have the correct values inside.

The old query

```
                $check_last_conversation = mysqli_query($MYSQLi,"select * from vp_pms_messages inner join vp_pms_group_users on vp_pms_messages.id = vp_pms_group_users.message_id and vp_pms_messages.group_id = vp_pms_group_users.group_id where vp_pms_group_users.from_username = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($MYSQLi,$session_username)."' and vp_pms_group_users.from_del = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($MYSQLi,'0')."' or vp_pms_group_users.to_username = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($MYSQLi,$session_username)."' and vp_pms_group_users.to_del = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($MYSQLi,'0')."' group by vp_pms_messages.group_id ".$order_data_by_this." desc limit 8");
```

The Wordpress one

```
                $check_last_conversation = $wpdb->get_results("select * from ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_messages inner join ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users on ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_messages.id = ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users.message_id and ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_messages.group_id = ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users.group_id where ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users.from_username = '".$session_uid."' and ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users.from_del = '0' or ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users.to_username = '".$session_uid."' and ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_group_users.to_del = '0' group by ".$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_messages.group_id ".$order_data_by_this." desc limit 8");
```

Could it be some encoding issue? Cn you give me some directions? Thanks.

Comment: How have you determined that you're "getting no results at all"?

Comment: Hello @eggyal thanks for your answer. I see the difference by printing `print_r($check_last_converstion)`

Answer (score 0):

I assume your wp table prefix is `vp_`. If that's so, by doing `$wpdb->prefix."vp_pms_messages` you will get `vp_vp_pms_messages` which is non-existent table. Same goes for other tables. You can also check your php error logs as well as use plugin called Query Monitor to see if there are any error and other debugging

Comment: Hello Igor! I already use Query Monitor and my table prefix is `wp_qsdn_`. Of course the first example is not using prefix because it's buit in external mysql database.

Comment: @XiLab did you set `global $wpdb` before query? Have you tried running the query you can see in query monitor via phpmyadmin or whatever mysql client you like? Are results returned or are there any errors?

Comment: I've set the `global`. I'm going to try to monitor the query through phpmyadmin! I let you know!

Answer (score 0):

Have you set `global $wpdb` in your function?

If it's not that, then check the value `$wpdb->last_error` after the call to see what the issue may be.

Comment: Yes I've set the `global` but I didn't try to debug my query. Let me try!